# SAS: Bars in Gchart are stacked

Tags: sas

I am trying to use Gchart in SAS to plot the values I've got, here is my code:

```
title "WOE Trend of VarA.";
proc gchart data=work.VarA;
    vbar VarB / 
        type=sum sumvar = VarA ASCENDING 
        subgroup = VarA nolegend
    raxis=axis1
    maxis=axis2
    autoref clipref
    width=32;
run;
```

There are four observations in table `VarA`, thus I expect to see four bars appear in the plot. However, in practive, there are two of the bars are stacked together that formed a stacked bar chart as follows. Also, the values of the observations are integers, however, there are decimals in the X-axis.

[image]

I guess I must have missed something in the option part since I am very new to this. Can anyone give me a clue that what am I wrong and how can I fix it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you have is

```
VarA  Varb
42    0.75
20    0.75
35   -0.75
28    2.25
```

That would generate the above chart.  If you didn't subgroup by VarA, you'd get a single bar 62 long for the first observation instead of splitting it partway through.  Summing and subgrouping by the same variable doesn't make a whole lot of sense, to me, but it depends on what you're trying to do I suppose.

The decimals are likely in the data, and are just rounded by your format.  If you want more useful help, you might post your actual data and code.